# Remote mounting from wsl to win10

Tags: ssh, wsl-2, sshfs

i have a question about mounting a folder to win10.
My university is using ubuntu on their machines, but at home i'm using win10. 
Now i managed to install wsl2 and access my computer, via proxyjumnp, at the university. 
 
Now i want to mount a folder from the pc at university to my home computer, using sshfs. The problem is, that if i do something like this "sshfs uni-pc:/home../folderToMount /mnt/f/localDir" i get the error "fusermount: mounting over filesystem type 0x01021997 is forbidden".  
If i try to mount it inside the wsl vm "sshfs uni-pc:/home../folderToMount /home/user/wsl-localDir" i can access the data in the terminal. But if i then try to access the mounted folder in windows explorer (with \\wsl$ and then navigating to the mounted folder), i cant open the folder and i'm getting a message, that i dont have the permission to access it. 
Is there a workaround for this problem or do i have to mount the folder through i.e powershell ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `user_allow_other` to /etc/fuse.conf.

Then you can execute `sshfs` with the `-o allow_other` argument:

```
sshfs uni-pc:/home../folderToMount /home/user/wsl-localDir -o allow_other
```